# Ruby Rspec Mock Same instance to behave different in the first and second call

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a code that looks like this:

```
def call(some_id:)

          verify_before = @verify.call(some_id)
          return verify_before if verify_before.sucess?
          did_something = @processor.call(some_id)
          return did_something unless did_something.sucess?
          @verify.call(some_id)
end
```

I would like to mock `@verify` so in the first time it will return `sucess?` = `false` and on the second call it will return `true`

What is the best approach?

Comment: Dependency injection is one way to do it, if you can find a way to pass a custom `@verify` from the tests

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can tell RSpec mocks to return different values on each call. The following example would return `false` on the first call and `true` on all later calls:

```
allow(@verify).to receive(:sucess?).and_return(false, true)
```

How to integrate that into your test depend on how you set `@verify` and how your tests look in general.